the question is relation to build exception in flutter
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_sound:verifyReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:C:\Users\thaku\OneDrive\Desktop\MieRideDriver\MieRideDriver\build\flutter_sound\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:2536: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
I upgrade the package flutter sound but then it shows this
Because no versions of rename match >3.0.2 <4.0.0 and rename 3.0.2 depends on logger ^2.0.2+1, rename ^3.0.2 requires logger ^2.0.2+1.
And because flutter_sound >=8.3.10 <9.3.0+1 depends on logger ^1.1.0, rename ^3.0.2 is incompatible with flutter_sound >=8.3.10 <9.3.0+1.
So, because mie_ride_driver depends on both rename ^3.0.2 and flutter_sound ^8.4.0, version solving failed.
You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

Try upgrading your constraint on flutter_sound: flutter pub add flutter_sound:^9.6.0
exit code 1

And when I use lower version of flutter sound the same problem facing above
Can anyone help me?

There's 36 answers in that linked Q&A, so hopefully you can find your answer there.

Did you try this: "Try upgrading your constraint on flutter_sound: flutter pub add flutter_sound:^9.6.0 "
